# MQL4 Drawing a Dynamic Rectangle_Label with a Text in It

Tags: object, label, mql4, drawrectangle

I am trying to draw a Rectangle Label with a text in it every tick.. I want a text to fit exactly in to a Rectangle_Label.. As a text i am using Label..  But cant get it to work exactly.. It is not correctly situated..

In Fact i would like to create a class that would do it all in one... Just like a rectangle with text in it that would be always having same co ordinance and size etc..

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
 bool createRectangleLabel(long chart_ID,string name,string labelName,int shift,double price,string text,double xSize,double ySize,double xOffSet,double yOffSet,double xDistance,double yDistance)
     {
      if(ObjectCreate(chart_ID,labelName,OBJ_RECTANGLE_LABEL,0,TimeCurrent()-shift,price))
    {
     Print(xDistance+"  "+yDistance);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,labelName,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,clrBlack);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,labelName,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,xDistance);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,labelName,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,yDistance);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,labelName,OBJPROP_YSIZE,ySize);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,labelName,OBJPROP_XSIZE,xSize);
     ObjectSetString(chart_ID,labelName,OBJPROP_TEXT,text);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_ANCHOR,ANCHOR_CENTER);

     return true;
    }
  else
    {
     Print("createRectangleLabel return error code: ",GetLastError());
     Print("+--------------------------------------------------------------+");
     return false;
    }
 }
   bool createLineText(long chart_ID,string name,string labelName,int shift,double price,string text)
 {
  int xDistance=0;
  int yDistance=0;
  int xSize,xOffSet;
  int ySize,yOffSet;
  bool i=ChartTimePriceToXY(chart_ID,0,TimeCurrent(),price,xDistance,yDistance);

  if(ObjectCreate(chart_ID,name,OBJ_LABEL,0,TimeCurrent()-shift,price))
    {
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,clrWhite);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,xDistance);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,yDistance);
     ObjectSetString(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_TEXT,text);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_ANCHOR,ANCHOR_CENTER);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_COLOR,clrWhite);
     ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,10);
     xSize = ObjectGet(name,OBJPROP_XSIZE);
     ySize = ObjectGet(name,OBJPROP_YSIZE);
     xOffSet = ObjectGet(name,OBJPROP_XOFFSET);
     yOffSet = ObjectGet(name,OBJPROP_YOFFSET);
     TextGetSize(name,xSize,ySize);
     createRectangleLabel(chart_ID,name,labelName,shift,price,text,xSize,ySize,xOffSet,yOffSet,xDistance,yDistance);
     return true;
    }
  else
    {
     Print("createLineText return error code: ",GetLastError());
     Print("+--------------------------------------------------------------+");
     return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking along the right lines when you say that you'd like to create a class. Fortunately for you, the `standard library` already includes all the classes you need to make chart objects. [Documentation](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/standardlibrary/chart_object_classes/obj_controls/cchartobjectrectlabel)

Example Indicator:

```
#property strict
#property indicator_chart_window

#include <ChartObjects\ChartObjectsTxtControls.mqh>

class MyRectLabel : public CChartObjectRectLabel
{
   CChartObjectLabel m_label;
public:
   bool Create(long chart, const string name, const int window, 
               const int X, const int Y, const int sizeX, const int sizeY)
   {
      if(!CChartObjectRectLabel::Create(chart,name,window,X,Y,sizeX,sizeY))
         return false;
      return m_label.Create(chart, name + "_", window, X + 8, Y + 12);
   }
   bool Color(const color clr){
      return m_label.Color(clr);
   }
   bool Description(const string text){
      return m_label.Description(text);
   }
   bool FontSize(const int size){
      return m_label.FontSize(size);
   }
   bool ToolTip(const string text){
      return (this.ToolTip(text) && m_label.Tooltip(text));
   }
};
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
MyRectLabel rect_label;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
   if(!rect_label.Create(0, "rlabel", 0, 5, 25, 100, 50)
      || !rect_label.BackColor(clrWhiteSmoke)
      || !rect_label.Description("LABEL!")
      || !rect_label.Tooltip("I am a rectangle label")
      || !rect_label.Color(clrBlack)
      || !rect_label.FontSize(18)
   )
      return INIT_FAILED;
   return INIT_SUCCEEDED;
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
{ 
   static double last_price = 0.;
   rect_label.Description(DoubleToString(Bid, _Digits));
   if(Bid > last_price)
      rect_label.Color(clrLimeGreen);
   else
      rect_label.Color(clrRed);
   last_price = Bid;
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Nice... Curious why i haven't found anything pointing me that way on my google search...    Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `ObjectCreate()` every tick - it would return an error 4200.
If you check the object exists before creating, that would help. Alternative approach would be to try to create the object and assign it with some necessary properties (e.g., color of the object, anchor etc) in one block, and move it in another.

```
if(ObjectFind(chart_id,labelName)<0){
   if(ObjectCreate(chart_ID,labelName,OBJ_RECTANGLE_LABEL,0,TimeCurrent()-shift,price)){
      ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,labelName,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,clrBlack);//etc.
   }
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,labelName,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,xDistance);
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,labelName,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,yDistance);//if you need to move the object or take other steps each tick, e.g. update text - do it here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i have that handled in other part of the code...  My question was related to assurance of the proper positioning of LABEL object and RECTANGLE_LABEL... I want them together at all the time at the same position changing every tick... Thank you...

Comment: My answer is exactly for your situation. You create the objects at `OnInit()` section, and then move the objects at `OnTick()` block by checking that the object exists (if deleted manually - ok, then create it again), and `ObjectSetInteger()` after `ObjectFind()`)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but please make sure that you understand a question before you answer.. I was seriously asking something else rather than handling creation and deletion of objects.. I have that handled but have something else not handled.. Would appreciate your effort that direction..

Comment: I am having other class that makes sure objects are deleted before they are created..  I Am asking for help in order to keep graphical location of these two objects at the same spot at all the time...